# Jenkins failed in bower package fetch

Tags: jenkins, github, bower

Jenkins failed in running bower package with error

> exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/metafizzy/fizzy-ui-utils.git/': Failed to connect
>   to github.com port 443: Timed out

It was working well before all the time. No package or version is changed but issue is replicating again & again. Server running jenkins is able to access `"https://github.com/metafizzy/fizzy-ui-utils.git"`, no issue accessing site in https.

What is issue here? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out to be github changed something recently that broke this:

> On February 22, 2018 19:00 UTC (11:00 am PST) GitHub discontinued
>   support for the cryptographically weak TLS 1.0 & 1.1 protocols and
>   only support connections with the TLS 1.2 protocol

See the GitHub Engineering blog post for more details about this change:
https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

**Solution**

---

Upgrading git client for windows on which jenkins build happens is the solution for the issue